# Styling Angular 2 Psuedo Elements (directive elements?)

Tags: css, angular, angular-ui-router, centering

I'm trying to horizontally center an element that is a child of the router-outlet, but it's not working. I think a parent of a centered element needs to have a physical width so the child has something to center to. But since the router-outlet is a pseudo element (I think that's what you call it), I'm not able to apply a width. I can apply a border to it for some reason, but no width... So how am I supposed to center within an element with no width? I MUST be missing something obvious here. I can't imagine an issue so obvious would be present in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

router-outlet is not a psudo element , it's a proper tag but might miss some initial properties.

Try applying this to your root css ( app.css ) and make sure app.ts has **encapsulation:viewEncapsulation.None**

```
router-outlet {

  display : block;
  position:relative;

}
```

Comment: display:block absolutely fixed it. Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

There are no childs of `router-outlet`. Components added by the router are added as siblings. You might use something like

```
router-outlet + * {
  display : block;
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Does this change everything that is sitting after router-outlet ? Do we want to do that ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe it is (and not sure on router-outlet)...  Divs usually cover 100%.  If you nest something like a span you could get results.